# Mute text notifications for single conversation only

Tags: sms

I have a single conversation on my phone that is updated often. I want to mute text notifications for this conversation only.

Answer (score 1):

If it is your app, then you could provide a provision for this by maintaining a flag. Else, if it is Android's SMS app or Hangout, then long press the conversation. It will provide mute notification option in Toolbar.